# Number of non-identity elements of order $7$ in a group

Tags: combinatorics

> If $x \neq e \in$ group $G$ s.t. $x^7 = e$, then $(x^i)^7 = e$ for all $i \in 1\le i\le $6 implying the number of $x \neq e \in G$ with $x^7 = e$ is $6n$ for any positive integer $n$

Wondering(not a proof) about the $6n$ part. Suppose there are two elements in $G$ with the given property. Call them $y, z$. Then $(y^1)^7 = e, (y^2)^7 = e, \ldots, (y^6)^7 = e$. Similarly for $z$. Then in total, there are $12$ such elements. In general, if there are $n$ elements in $G$ with the given property, then there are $6n$ elements in $G$ with the same property. Does that make sense? Do we assume/know $x \neq e \in G (x^7 = e)$ is not unique? If any of this is incorrect, where does $6n$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two subgroups of order $7$ either are identical or intersect at $e$.

Therefore, the subgroups of order $7$ induce a partition on the set of elements of order $7$.

There are exactly $6$ elements of order $7$ in each subgroup of order $7$.

Therefore, there are $6n$ elements of order $7$ if there are $n$ subgroups of order $7$.

Answer (score 2):

Any group of order $7$ is cyclic. Any non-identical subgroup of $G$ that has order $7$ can only intersect at identity element $e$(otherwise the non-identity element will generate both groups and these groups are identical).

Suppose there are $n$ subgroup of order $7$ in $G$, each subgroup has an identity and $6$ other elements of order $7$. By the argument above, there are 6n elements of order $7$ in $G$.